# Proving Irregularity of $L = \{ a^mb^nb^n \mid nm \ge 3 \} $

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to prove the irregularity of the following language:

$$L = \{ a^mb^nb^n \mid nm \ge 3 \} $$

I tried to demonstrate that it doesn't verifies the Pumping Lemma but for all words I tried it seems to accept all of them.

Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: I think it might be regular

Comment: (Um - sure about $b^nb^n$? looks like $b^{2n}$.)

Comment: @greybeard is what my teacher wrote ^^"

Comment: This doesn't look very irregular to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is regular since $a^*(bb)^* \setminus L$ is regular:

$a^*(bb)^*\setminus L = a^* \cup (bb)^* \cup \{a^mb^{2n}|1\leq mn < 3\}$

The last language of the union is finite thus regular.

Answer (score 2):

Your language is regular. Indeed, the condition $nm \geq 3$ is equivalent to ($n = 1$ and $m \geq 3$) or ($n \geq 3$ and $m = 1$) or ($n \geq 2$ and $m \geq 2$). It is described by the regular expression $$ a (bb)^3(bb)^* + a^3a^*bb + a^2a^*(bb)^2(bb)^*. $$